# Convert asp:Table to excel format

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, excel

I am able to to generate excel file from asp:table,but after generating excel file while opening file it gives warning .**file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension** I have found solution to this warning from this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Solution-ASPNet-GridView-Export-to-Excel-The-file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in-a-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension.aspx

so i have used ClosedXML Library but while adding data to excel sheet it's accepting datable,dataset format only and i got data in string format so it's generating blank excel sheet. please check code i have tried.

```
            LoadDetailsToTable();

            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            tbl_loctbl.RenderControl(hw);
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("asd");
                ws.Cell(2, 1).InsertTable(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format(@"attachment;filename=newfile.xlsx"));

                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.Close();
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
```

Here **LoadDetailsToTable**() function load data to asp table.**tbl_loctbl** is table id.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the two markups you're using are incompatible. HTML table markup in Excel is supported, but its not in OpenXML which is what your library is expecting to output.

Under the hood, Excel is expecting a valid XML file format; html, while loosely supported, isn't the native xlsx format.

There are libraries available that will convert html to openxml on the internet, however this can be solved by iterating over your dataset and actually adding cells and rows using the [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478153%28v=office.15%29.aspx)